# C# Web service consuming error in ABAP. Please supply a valid soap action

Tags: c#, web-services, abap

We have developed a web service which is consumed fine by a C# .NET application but this web service can't be consumed by an ABAP-based application getting the error :

> **Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.**
>
> [image]

What would be the problem?

WSDL File:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://sabretch.com/psr" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://sabretch.com/psr">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sabretch.com/psr">
<s:element name="SendChangeLog">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="toDetails" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="subject" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="arr_psrAlertLogItems" type="tns:ArrayOfObj"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfObj">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Obj" nillable="true" type="tns:Obj"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Obj">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ChangeDateTime" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Line" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FieldTecnicalName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ChangedUser" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="SendChangeLogResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SendChangeLogResult" type="s:boolean"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="SendChangeLogSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendChangeLog"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SendChangeLogSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendChangeLogResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PSREmailServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="SendChangeLog">
<wsdl:input message="tns:SendChangeLogSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:SendChangeLogSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PSREmailServiceSoap" type="tns:PSREmailServiceSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SendChangeLog">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://sabretch.com/psr/SendChangeLog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="PSREmailServiceSoap12" type="tns:PSREmailServiceSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SendChangeLog">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://sabretch.com/psr/SendChangeLog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PSREmailService">
<wsdl:port name="PSREmailServiceSoap" binding="tns:PSREmailServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://122.255.30.75:8090/WebServices/PSREmailService.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="PSREmailServiceSoap12" binding="tns:PSREmailServiceSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://122.255.30.75:8090/WebServices/PSREmailService.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending the SOAP request, part of the HTTP Header data must include a SOAP Action field in order to correctly identify (using the WDSL) what methods to execute. In C# this is processed automatically based on the action provided when sending the message which explains why you would be getting problems now.

Being as I'm not too well versed in SAP, I can't provide an example, however this knowledge should start you off on the right track.

Comment: Thanks James it was fixed it was a issue with WSDL namespace we kept the default namespace and it worked ! thanks for help